# Is "undismissable" correct?

Tags: word-request

I want to say that a notification is undismissable. What I mean is that you can not dismiss this notification.

Is it right to say this:

> ten undismissable notifications are existed.

Comment: I don't know that word, but I can suggest "critical notifications"

Comment: "**are existed**" is incorrect... "**ten _____ notifications exist.**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Undismissable** (or **undismissible**) is an infrequently used word meaning *that which cannot be dismissed*. ([**Source**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259837/a-neutral-alternative-to-notable))

You may also be looking for "**irremovable**" or "**non-dismissible**"